# Object fit fallback on IE issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make `object-fit` work on IE using `Modernizr`.

This is my html:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
    <div class="post featuredpost">
        <a href="'.$cblok['alias'].'.html" class="hoverBorder">
            <span class="cftoverlay"><img src="images/overlay.png"></span>
            <span class="hoverBorderWrapper">
                <img src="'.$image.'" class="img-responsive featuredarticles" width="370" height="400" alt="" title="">
                <span class="theHoverBorder"></span>
            </span>
        </a>
        <div class="post-details">
            <h3 class="m_title"><a href="'.$cblok['alias'].'.html">'.$cblok['title'].'</a></h3>
            <em>    <a>'.strip_tags($shortstr).'</a></em>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my js:

```
if ( ! Modernizr.objectfit ) {
    tpj('.featuredpost').each(function () {
        var $container = tpj(this),
                imgUrl = $container.find('img').prop('src');
        if (imgUrl) {
            $container
                .css('backgroundImage', 'url(' + imgUrl + ')')
                .addClass('compat-object-fit');
        }
    });
}
```

This code adds the overlay.png as a background image, which makes sense since that is the first img tag the code comes across. I need the second image to be the background image (the one with the `img-responsive` class).

How can I make sure the second image is used?